# How to go back to the previous screen and reload all function of the first screen?

Tags: flutter

I have a problem. How to go back to the previous screen and reload all function of the first screen?

On page 1, I have several functions to load all data from json and calculations.
And when user goes to page 2 and does an insert to the json and when the suer goes back to page 1, reload all the functions on page 1.

I have function like below:

```
Future<void> CountBalanced() {
    ListDetailPaymentTransactions(global.strtransidtrans);
    global.doubbalanced = global.inttotalpayment - global.doubtranstotaltrans;
    print(global.inttotalpayment - global.doubtranstotaltrans);
}
```

Currently I found this code:

```
Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => CashPayment())).whenComplete(CountBalanced);
```

But the issue is when the user goes back to page 1 the functions are running all the time and wont stop.

I noticed it when I tried to print the result.

Is there any way to stop it? And is there any better way to reload all the function on page 1?

Answer (score 0):

For stopping your function when navigation try disposing them

```
 @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
  }
```

To reloading the methods

```
@override
  void didUpdateWidget(ClassName oldWidget) {
    super.didUpdateWidget(oldWidget);
    if (comparision) {

     //your initState
    }
  }
```

For more information
https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/State/didUpdateWidget.html